# Async Cursor Iteration with Asynchronous Sub-task

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to perform an iteration over a mongoDB collection w/o numeric key(`_id`). The collection only has random strings as an _id, and the size of the collection is massive, thus loading up the whole documents on RAM using `.toArray()` is not a viable option. plus I want to perform asynchronous task on each element. the usage of `.map()` or `.each()`, `.forEach()` is limited because of the asynchronous nature of the task. I tried to run the task with those mentioned methods but it did of course conflicted with asynchronous task, returned pending promises instead of proper results.

**example**

```
async function dbanalyze(){

  let cursor = db.collection('randomcollection').find()
  for(;;){
    const el = cursor.hasNext() ? loaded.next() : null;
    if(!cursor) break
    await performAnalyze(cursor) // <---- this doesn't return a document but just a cursor object
  }

}
```

how can I iterate over mongoDB collection using only `for()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`Cursor.hasNext()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#hasNext) method is also "asynchronous", so you need to `await` that as well. Same goes for [`Cursor.next()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#next). Therefore the actual "loop" usage really should be a `while`:

```
async function dbanalyze(){

  let cursor = db.collection('randomcollection').find()
  while ( await cursor.hasNext() ) {  // will return false when there are no more results
    let doc = await cursor.next();    // actually gets the document
    // do something, possibly async with the current document
  }

}
```

As noted in the comments, eventually [`Cursor.hasNext()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#hasNext) will return `false` when the cursor is actually depleted, and the [`Cursor.next()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#next) is the thing that is actually retrieving each value from the cursor. You could do other structures and `break` the loop when `hasNext()` is `false`, but it more naturally lends itself to a `while`.

These are still "async", so you need to `await` the promise resolution on each, and that was the main fact you were missing.

As for [`Cursor.map()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#map), then you are probably missing the point that it can be marked with an `async` flag on the provided function as well:

```
 cursor.map( async doc => {                   // We can mark as async
    let newDoc = await someAsyncMethod(doc);  // so you can then await inside
    return newDoc;
 })
```

But you still actually want to "iterate" that somewhere, unless you can get away with using `.pipe()` to some other output destination.

Also the `async/await` flags also make [`Cursor.forEach()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#forEach) *"more practical again"*, as it's one common flaw was not being able to simply handle an "inner" asynchronous call, but with these flags you can now do so with ease, though admittedly since you **must** use a callback, you probably want to wrap this in a Promise :

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
  cursor.forEach(
    async doc => {                              // marked as async
      let newDoc = await someAsyncMethod(doc);  // so you can then await inside
      // do other things
    },
    err => {
      // await was respected, so we get here when done.
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve();
    }
  )
);
```

Of course there has always been ways to apply this with either callbacks or plain Promise implementations, but it's the "sugar" of `async/await` than actually makes this look much cleaner.

#### NodeJS v10.x and MongoDB Node driver 3.1.x and up

And the favorite version uses `AsyncIterator` which is now enabled in NodeJS v10 and upwards. It's a much cleaner way to iterate

```
async function dbanalyze(){

  let cursor = db.collection('randomcollection').find()
  for await ( let doc of cursor ) {
    // do something with the current document
  }    
}
```

Which *"in a way"* comes back to what the question originally asked as to using a `for` loop since we can do the `for-await-of` syntax here fore supporting iterable which supports the correct interface. And the `Cursor` does support this interface.

---

If you're curios, here's a listing I cooked up some time ago to demonstrate various cursor iteration techniques. It even includes a case for [Async Iterators from a generator function](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/async-iterators-and-generators/):

```
const Async = require('async'),
      { MongoClient, Cursor } = require('mongodb');

const testLen = 3;
(async function() {

  let db;

  try {
    let client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/');

    let db = client.db('test');
    let collection = db.collection('cursortest');

    await collection.remove();

    await collection.insertMany(
      Array(testLen).fill(1).map((e,i) => ({ i }))
    );

    // Cursor.forEach
    console.log('Cursor.forEach');
    await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      collection.find().forEach(
        console.log,
        err => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          resolve();
        }
      );
    });

    // Async.during awaits cursor.hasNext()
    console.log('Async.during');
    await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

      let cursor = collection.find();

      Async.during(
        (callback) => Async.nextTick(() => cursor.hasNext(callback)),
        (callback) => {
          cursor.next((err,doc) => {
            if (err) callback(err);
            console.log(doc);
            callback();
          })
        },
        (err) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          resolve();
        }
      );

    });

    // async/await allows while loop
    console.log('async/await while');
    await (async function() {

      let cursor = collection.find();

      while( await cursor.hasNext() ) {
        let doc = await cursor.next();
        console.log(doc);
      }

    })();

    // await event stream
    console.log('Event Stream');
    await new Promise((end,error) => {
      let cursor = collection.find();

      for ( let [k,v] of Object.entries({ end, error, data: console.log }) )
        cursor.on(k,v);
    });

    // Promise recursion
    console.log('Promise recursion');
    await (async function() {

      let cursor = collection.find();

      function iterate(cursor) {
        return cursor.hasNext().then( bool =>
          (bool) ? cursor.next().then( doc => {
            console.log(doc);
            return iterate(cursor);
          }) : Promise.resolve()
        )
      }

      await iterate(cursor);

    })();

    // Uncomment if node is run with async iteration enabled
    // --harmony_async_iteration


    console.log('Generator Async Iterator');
    await (async function() {

      async function* cursorAsyncIterator() {
        let cursor = collection.find();

        while (await cursor.hasNext() ) {
          yield cursor.next();
        }

      }

      for await (let doc of cursorAsyncIterator()) {
        console.log(doc);
      }

    })();


    // This is supported with Node v10.x and the 3.1 Series Driver
    await (async function() {

      for await (let doc of collection.find()) {
        console.log(doc);
      }

    })();

    client.close();

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    process.exit();
  }

})();
```

Comment: Wow this provides so much insight on Async task w/ MongoDB iteration. Honestly I didn't even know it is possible to declare `.map()` callback as async. I think I will use this knowledge a lot in the future. Thank you!