# mongodb stops while iterating over large DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is a follow-up question of this Stackoverflow question: [Async Cursor Iteration with Asynchronous Sub-task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848883/async-cursor-iteration-with-asynchronous-sub-task). with a slightly different turn this time.

While iterating over MongoDB documents the task stops in the middle if the target DB size is too large. (more than 3000 documents in a single collection and each document consists of lengthy texts, so `.toArray` is not really feasible due to memory limit. 3000 is just a part of the whole data and the full data might be more than 10,000 documents.) I've noticed if the number of documents in a collection is larger than approx. 750, it just stops in the middle of the task.

I've searched over previous Stackoverflow questions to solve this: some say iteration on a large collection requires using `stream`, `each` or `map` instead of `for/while` with `cursor`. When I tried these recommendations in real life, non of them did work. They also just stops in the middle, bears almost no difference from `for/while` iteration. I don't really like the idea of expanding `timeout` since it may leave the `cursor` behind drifting around in the memory but it also didn't work.

*every method below is under `async` condition*

**stream method**

```
const cursor = db.collections('mycollection').find()
cursor.on('data', doc => {
  await doSomething(doc)//do something with doc here
})
```

**while/for method(just replace `while` with `for`)**

```
const cursor = db.collections('mycollection').find()
while ( await cursor.hasNext() ) {
  let doc = await cursor.next()
  await doSomething(doc)
}
```

**map/each/foreach method(replace `map` with `foreach/each`)**

```
const cursor = db.collections('mycollection').find()
cursor.map(async doc=>{
  await doSomething(doc)
})
```

none of them shows any difference to the other. They just stop when it iterates around approx. 750 documents and just hang.  I've even tried registering each document on `Promise.all` queue and do the `async/await` task at once later so that cursor won't spend too much time while iterating but the same problem arises.

EDIT: I think `doSomething()` confuses the other readers. So I have created a sample code so that you can reproduce the problem.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const MongoUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'
const MongoDBname = 'testDB'
const MongoCollection = 'testCollection'
const moment = require('moment')

const getDB = () =>
  new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    MongoClient.connect(MongoUrl,(err,client)=>{
      if(err) return reject(err)
      console.log('successfully connected to db')
      return resolve(client.db(MongoDBname))
      client.close()
    })
  })

;(async ()=>{
  console.log(`iteration begins on ${moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss')} ------------`)
  let db = await getDB() //receives mongodb

  //iterate through all db articles...
  const cursor = await db.collection(MongoCollection).find()
  const maxDoc = await cursor.count()
  console.log('Amount of target document:' + maxDoc)
  let count = 0
  //replace this with stream/while/map...any other iteration methods
  cursor.each((err,doc)=>{
    count ++
    console.log(`preloading doc No.${count} async ${(count / maxDoc * 100).toFixed(2)}%`)
  })
})()
```

**My apologies.** on the test run. it actually iterated all the documents...I think I really have done something wrong with the other parts. I'll elaborate this one with the other parts causing the trouble.

Comment: What is `doSomething()` actually doing? The highest probability here is that it's actually that code which is causing the problem. Note also that neither your `.map()` or "stream" approaches are actually "waiting" on each iteration, as you are missing the needed step each time. But for starters, let's be sure that even the point of `doSomething()` cannot be achieved in a better way. It probably can.

Comment: You're right. `.map()` or `stream` above don't really `await` for `asynchronous` calls. Sorry if it's caused confusion. However, when I tried to debug it with `console.log()` or any other test methods on this iteration itself, without the actual `doSomething()`, the progress still stops at the similar point. As I mentioned above, I've even used `Promise` to avoid any delay due to `await` but same problem still happens. My function may have a problem, but the cursor doesn't even reach the end in the first place.

Comment: No **"you're wrong"** because both actually **do** have a way to await "the next loop iteration" it's just that your interpretation is **doing it wrong**. What I asked you for and the **only way to solve your problem** is to actually **"show what the `doSomething()` code is doing"**. You are almost certainly doing something wrong inside that, and likely not awaiting callbacks or promises in that code. In short, you're jumping to the false conclusion that this has to do with the "cursor", where that is not the real problem.

Comment: Sorry I don't get this. I've really deleted all other parts other than just logging(`console.log()`) and counting(`count++`) to check if I have done anything wrong with `doSomething()` and it still stops at similar point. What have I done wrong with the *function* when there is no *function* actually available???? I'll edit the post with sample so that you can reproduce the problem without `doSomething()`

Comment: Umm. You're closing the connection `client.close()` **before** the actual program completes. Also just simply `const client = await MongoClient.connect(MongoUrl)`, and do that in the normal scope. Your whole "connect function" is basically flawed. I actually gave you code that clearly shows this on your last question. I suggest you review it again.

Comment: update: I've finished the project using `.toArray()` due to a time constraint. luckily up to ten thousands the performance doesn't get any lower. This is not a recommended solution but I wrongly constructed the whole system in the first place.

Comment: Moral of the story: anybody who builds up a mongodb(NoSQL) system, put sequence numbers & category keys as index on documents if necessary. I couldn't find any better solutions; getting rid of sequence numbers is really a bad idea when analyzing the whole db.