# Node.js, Mongodb & MongoClient locally - how many connections possible? "Error shutting down socket"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database-connection

I am running node.js and MongoDB locally. CPU is a AMD Ryzen 7 1800 with 32,0 GB RAM.
My application takes in parameters and then calls functions in order to manipulate meal plans.
Everything works perfect and fast until I scale up.

Using a for loop to start the inital function with every grocery store combination possible, I start to get errors when having around 680 parallel connections open to MongoDB.
Error message in the command line: "Error shutting down socket"

This only happens sometimes. When I scale down to roughly 520 (reducing the number of grocery store combinations), everything works very fast and fine (output roughly 100k recipes).

My question: 
1. Why is this happening?
2. Can I somehow configure Node.js/MongoClient/MongoDB so that it is utilizing the potential of my rig?

Here is a kind of sample code extraction:

```
//*File_Recipes* (Here I read out all recipes of one collection)

  //Import of the function that adapts the recipes
  var adapt = require("./File_AdaptIngredientOne")
  //Export of this module, as it will be called with different shop1&shop2- 
  //combos
  module.exports = async function (shop1, shop2) {  
   client.connect(url, function (err, client) {
   if(err) throw err;

   var db = client.db("database");
   var collection = db.collection("Recipes");
   var collection2 = db.collection("adaptedRecipes");

   var cursor = collection.find(query);
   //Now, I call the function adapt() with every found recipe
   //The function adapt needs to read data in MongoDB and insert&update 
   //instances
   cursor.ForEach(
      function(doc) {
          adaptIngredientOne(doc, collection, collection2, shop1, shop2);
          adaptIngredientTwo(doc, collection, collection2, shop1, shop2);
      });
   });
  };

//*File_AdaptIngredientOne* (Here, every ingredient of a recipe will be 
//adapted to a specific shop and then inserted into a collection

  module.exports = async function(doc, collection, collection2, shop1, 
  shop2){
  //Here I find a specific ingredient of a recipe in a specific shop
  var ingredientOne = await collection.findOne({
                         searchTerm: doc.Name + shop1
                         })
  // Now, the amount of this ingredient is updated
  var amount = doc.Amount * ingredientOne.Amount
  // After that, the recipe with an updated ingredient is saved as a new 
  //grocery store specific recipe
  await collection2.insertOne({
   Name: doc.Name,
   Amount: amount,
   ...
   })

//*File_Shops* (Here, the function from *File_Recipes* is called with 
//different grocery store combinations

  var recipes = require("./File_Recipes")
  var grocery_stores = ["Aldi", "Lidl", "Edeka", ....]

  //I now call the recipes function with all grocery store combinations

  for (i=0; i < grocery_stores.length; i++) {
   for(n=i; n < grocery_stores.length; n++) {
    shop1 = grocery_stores[i];
    shop2 = grocery_stores[n];
    recipes(shop1, shop2);
   }
  }
```

Comment: *"Using a for loop....I start to get errors when having around 680 parallel connections"* - So that's your actual problem here. If it looks and walks like a duck, then think "duck" and not dinosaur. Stop looking at debugging the Mongo server and start correcting your code. You will be firing off callbacks without waiting for them to resolve, and you need to actually do that. We need to see "your code"  so we can actually show you what to do instead of the incorrect loop procedure you are doing right now.

Comment: You should post the code which you use to connect MongoDb. Also how do you measure how many db connection you have at a time?

Comment: @MattLong Exact.! I replicate the same steps for multiple different combinations of parameters (grocery store combinations). I am completely new, so connection pools is unknown territory for me.... I would appreaciate if you couldtake a look at the now provided sample code. It is extremely simplified, as every recipe has many different ingredients and after updating every ingredient, I once more update a recipes finally to add up macronutrients. (I use a Promise.all to do this)

Comment: @NeilLunn Hi Neil, first thanks for your comment. As you can see, I have provided some sample code. How could I achieve the above result without a *for loop* ? I am competely new and look forward to get some guidance from you guys. Keep in mind, my goal is just to calculate stuff for myself. There is no connection to the internet or user access/interaction so far.

Comment: @Khang Hi Khang. Thanks for your comment. When I start my initial loop, I can see in the command line, how many connections are now open. When it reaches roughly 680 connections, the *Error shutting down socket* starts to appear infrequently. I am looking forward to every kind of guidance. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are `adaptIngredientOne()` and `Two` actually doing? You also have some misconceptions of `async/await` in the code, but the basic premise is to make sure everything is a `Promise` and `await` each call. With a regular `while` loop as well and not using the `foreEach()`, which is actually really bad.

Comment: This should help [Async Cursor Iteration with Asynchronous Sub-task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49849363/2313887). I actually give a "run down" of various ways to iterate a cursor and work with async tasks being executed for each iteration. Your core problem here is you are not doing that, but the listing here is too extensive and incomplete to expect someone to do it for you. I suggest you learn what you "should do" and then apply it.

Comment: @NeilLunn I took your advice literally and did a udemy course. Thanks for that, it was really a wise decision. Now I completely transformed every ingle function into a promise and used async/await & Promise.all in order to exactly know what is going on. Still, as I start to fire many functions, after having roughly 680 connections to mongod open, I get an fatal error "CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

Comment: @NeilLunn if I only fire the start function with much less cases, everything works fine and very fast. My question would be, how many connections can be opened simultanously? Also, can I somehow  "tune" node so that it is taking my very strong rig into account (32GB Ram, Ryzen7)?

Comment: @NeilLunn I would just like to get an idea, which "topic" I would need to learn now in order to get an idea about how to make this happen. Async/Await now works perfect. I sepnt a lot of time on it, but it is not helping me finally....#

Comment: @MattLong could you please briefly explain, why 680 connections to one mongod process are not a good idea? I read that mongodb is capable of 1000's of connections at the same time. I replicated my code with mongoose, it worked well but was very slow.... I understood that only one action at a time can be done with a connection. As I have a lot of asynchronous actions, it is obviuos that many connections are needed. I am quite stuck as advice on how to "tune" is rare.... every hint would be appreciated.

Comment: MongoDB prefers horizontal scaling. SQL Server vertical. This is my oppinion.